# hide/show form fields based on dropdown choice with class tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a problem with the show/hide function on an app form. The app form is live here -> http://www.specialfinance.co.uk/introducers/submit-an-enquiry/secured-loans.html

Currently the form works as a multipage form (within javascript) which is fine, it's doing the job nicely, but what I can't figure out based on any of the Q&A guides I've looked thru on here (I've gone thru many google searches) is how to integrate a further show/hide script to hide the applicant 2 column if the dropdown at the top has a value of 1.

The column is a table with all the inputs in separate rows, so I was thinking that the easiest way would be to link to a class and then hide the class, but I have no idea how to do this.

I'm getting there with my knowledge of javascript, but this one seems to be a hurdle I can't get over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .change() (jQuery) with the dropdown list to see what the value is, then based off that, hide and show what you need.

```
$("#idOfDropDown").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        //Show  or Hide what you need .show()
    }
    else {
        //Show or Hide .hide()
});
```

Heres a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Szt59/1/ using a class.

Comment: I hate to be a pain, but is there any chance you could provide an example. I'm unsure how to implement this correctly. I'll have a go in the meantime and post back if i get stuck.

Comment: Absolutely, give me a few mins, ill fiddle one up.

Comment: thanks, my main prob is knowing how to get the javascript to hide a particular class.

Comment: ok i've updated the code on the live sheet and wrapped a div tag around the first row I'd like to hide, and it isn't working, any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? Would be much easier.

Comment: i can try, let me have a go.

Comment: are u around to have a look?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7rZmC/1/) is a quick and dirty example. It's easy to see how you can extend it.

```
$("#drop").change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() === "2" ) {
         $(".rest").slideDown("fast");   
    } else {
       $(".rest").slideUp("fast");     
   }
});
```

[Click to see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7rZmC/1/)
Edited.

Comment: ok i see how the demo works and that makes sense, but it works on the basis of displaying a div id. How would i make that display a class?

Comment: @tymeJV Why? `===` is strict equality operator.

Comment: My form currently works as a table so the rows are intertwined, so potentially i'm guessing i'm looking at either multple div id's, or a class tag.

Comment: @sagamon Use the class selector `.` instead of id `#`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7rZmC/1/)

Comment: @AndreiNemes my fault, didnt realize that, disregard my comment pls.